# Excel 2013 re-calculating very slowly?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I've had a recent os replacement win7 x64 (harddrive died and i got another and started from scratch). There is 1 volatile function.
The problem is - it didn't slow me down with the old installation.

At first i thought I've overburdened it with more stuff to do, but then it seemed suspicious and i finally rolled back to a much older version of my document to only find the delay applies there as well - except i never had it before.

If i copy text from outside of excel and paste it into a cell, it may take half a second to figure it out. (which is ok).
If i type the volatile formula it takes the same time and figures it out. (which is ok).

The problem comes when I copy a cell that contains the same text or formula and paste it onto the next cell - the software practically clogs for over a minute with its "Calculating: (6 Processors): xx%"... Which is weird as CPU never goes above 20% load with 2 browsers and photoshop in the background. Also with manual calculation it works in under 1 second when it triggers a recalc upon save file.

Is it the chip-set drivers, or some excel option i need to tweak i don't know, but there is definitely something going on thats making a mess. Any ideas?

It takes me more than five seconds to copy any cell to any other cell in the sample file. It used to take me half a second to do this in a 2mb document.

xlsM FILE:
http://dox.bg/files/dw?a=a38fbbbd13

xlsX FILE:
http://dox.bg/files/dw?a=f48a2ef6a4

And module code:

```
Function ReqOffset(ReqAdd As String, iOff As Integer) As String
Application.Volatile True
Dim V As Variant
Dim i As Integer

V = Split(ReqAdd, " ")
For i = LBound(V) To UBound(V) Step 2
    ReqOffset = Trim(ReqOffset) & " " & Range(V(i)).Cells(CInt(V(i + 1))).Offset(0, iOff).Value
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: we would need far more details and still it would be difficult to answer. "OS replacement" - from what to what? "The problem comes when..." - was that better with your previous settings? Does it work well on another pc?

Comment: You can try the file directly and see for yourself.  What else do you need? Os was win7 x64 and still is at new installation.

Comment: It may be better to post the problem function text for us to evaluate the problem. A macro-enabled workbook could be a vector for a virus.

Comment: Sure, added as another file, even though excel ask before it enables any macros for a new file...